# Which relation between $A$, $B$ and $C$ should be satisfied in order the infinite integral below vanish?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

While I am solving an elasticity situation I came across the following integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( q^2 (A+B\cos (qR))+q C \sin(qR) \right) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q = 0 \, , \quad\quad (0<r<R) \, ,
$$
wherein $A, B, C$ are real numbers.
I am looking for an equation between $A$, $B$ and $C$ to have this integral identically null.

Any hint of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Federiko

Comment: The relation should be non-trivial. It can be seen that $A=B=C=0$ satisfies the above equations.

Comment: Assume that $A=B=0$, does $\int_0^\infty q \sin(qR) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d}q=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} R} \int_0^\infty \cos(qR) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d}q =0$ for $r<R$ ? Thanks!